# Do we need to open a file to get its attributes?

Tags: linux, files, c

```
int stat(const char *filename, struct stat *buf);
int fstat(int fd, struct stat *buf);
```

Do we need to open a file to get its attributes?

To access the attributes of a file, do we need to access the file's entry in file desriptor table, in file table, and/or in vnode table?

Is `stat()` implemented by first calling `open()` to get a file descriptor of the given file, and then calling `fstat()` or something equivalent on the file descriptor?

Thanks.

Comment: They're both simple C wrapper of syscalls provided by kernel. I don't think one syscall would be implemented using another one, if talking about kernel implementation.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to open it.

The `stat()` syscall never involves a file descriptor anywhere.

In fact, you may be able to `stat()` some files that you don't have permission to `open()`.